# Scroll lag with Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a website with a little bit jquery movement in home page. But I noticed that there is a big lag when scrolling webpage with Chrome browser. With other browsers (I tried Mozilla, IE, Opera) it seems everyting ok. I tried to remove script which animates background elements, but the problem still exists.

What could possibly cause scroll lag?

You can take a look at website [here:](http://digijob.lt/oleg/)

Comment: How big are the images? The site took an age to load and glitches up on scrolling down in Safari too.

Answer (score 1):

Whoaaa bro. I'd tone down the amount of images and animations on your page. If it takes over 5 seconds to load a page there's somethin' wrong. So, my suggestion is try and clean up your scripts. Try to do multiple things with one small block of code. I'm guessing that the problem would be the amount of things you're trying to do at once, but I can't be sure.